# Looking for some advice in regards to hosting

Tags: magento-2.1, server-setup, pagespeed

We are currently moving over our website to a Magento platform and looking into what hosting we need to be able to run the store. I've ready that so many factors go into the web hosting that it's hard to decide with no information so I put together some stats in hope that somebody can give some feedback.

**Current Info:**

SKU's: 3,000 for now although will be going up to maybe 8,000

Daily Visitors Average: 50

Orders: The website we have now is old so it doesn't get loads of sales (couple a day)

**Current Server We Have:**

CPU: 4 vCore

RAM: 8 GB

SSD: 160 GB

Vesta CP control panel has been installed, running PHP 7.0.27

The website is the only website running on the server.

I currently have Varnish 4 installed with Magentos configuration along with Cloudflare enabled.

The database is hosted on another server (running Vesta CP control panel also):

**Database Server**

CPU: 2 vCore

RAM: 4 GB

SSD: 120 GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update on my situation.

I managed to get my website up to an acceptable speed.

I currently have 3,000 products on my website with a page speed of maybe 1-2 seconds with Varnish cache installed.

I am not using the database server listed above to host the database, both is done on the current server.

I have 4GB ram dedicated to the Varnish application, which to be honest was the reason I managed to get it to this speed.

Thanks